# ORDER BY A CUSTOM ORDER

Tags: sql-order-by, uppercase, lowercase, alphabetical, non-english

$words=$db->selectMultiRecords("select * from words where english like '$alphabet%' order by ......");

I have a list of words that I want to order by this order :

('a','b','g','G','d','D','e','f','k','K','h','p','o','x','q','i','j','l','m','n','u','r','R','V')

Uppercase letters and lowercase are not the same (d is not D)

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY` with `FIELD`:

```
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE english LIKE '$alphabet%'
ORDER BY FIELD(LEFT(english, 1),
               'a','b','g','G','d','D','e','f','k','K','h','p','o','x','q','i','j','l','m','n','u','r','R','V');
```

You seem to be using some PHP variant, but I don't recognize it, so I just gave the raw query.  Also, you should avoid using PHP variables inside your SQL strings; use prepared statements instead.

Comment: I used that, but it will only organized them by the first letter but if the first letter is the same it will not compare the second letter and etc ..

Comment: @Wassim Well what are the rules for sorting beyond the first letter?

Comment: the same as in alphabet , for exemple if we have ( advertise / advance / agency / aGency ) .. the order will be (agency / aGency / advance / advertise )  so the rule is order by first letter -- if we have same first letter pass to the next letter and keep going

Comment: Add sample data to your question and then show how it should sort.